# Animation: How to move a parabola in a continuous manner?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

How can I draw a graph of parabola `$f(x)=x^2$` and make vertical animation of this.So the graph moves to right and left side.This is my minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools} %includes amsmath
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, cap=round]

\draw[->] (-4.0,0) -- (4.0,0); 
\node[below] at (4.0, 0.0) {\textit{x}};
\draw[->] (0,-4.0) -- (0,4.0);
\node[left] at (0.0,4.0) {\textit{f(x)}};


\draw[blue, line width=1.75pt, domain=-2.00 : 2.00, samples=1500] plot[smooth](\x, {\x*\x });

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

How can I shift this parabola slowly to  3 units right and change the color and write `$f(x-3)$`.

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about what you want to do, since there are several ways do to such things. For example, do you want to plot the parabola using PGFplots or rather with Ti*k*Z? Do you intend to use multiple frames with beamer or should the output be interactive (using the `animate` package for example)?

Comment: I am thinking about interactive way to it. The graphs should be in a coordinat system and not in a box as in PGFPlots.

Comment: I have added now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `animate` package, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls, palindrome]{15}
\multiframe{33}{rt=-4+0.25}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \\clip (-5.5,-1.5) rectangle (5.5,9.5);
    
    \draw[->] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[above] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,9) node[above] {$y$};
    \path (0,0) node[below left] {$0$};

    \begin{scope}[shift={(\rt,0)}]
        \draw (-4,8) parabola bend (0,0) (4,8);
    \end{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{abs(\rt^2)/2}
    \node[fill=red, circle, inner sep=2pt] at (0,\y) {};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Applied to your MWE, your code could look like this (since I did not know which color you want to change to, I just chose red):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls, palindrome]{4}
\multiframe{4}{rt=0+1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, cap=round]
    
    \clip (-4.5,-4.5) rectangle (4.5,4.5);

    \draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0); 
    \node[below] at (4,0) {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    
    \ifdim\rt pt=0pt\relax
        \node[left] at (0,4) {$f(x)$};
    \else
        \node[left] at (0,4) {$f(x - \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\rt})$};
    \fi

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\colorgrad}{\rt/(4-1)*100}
    \draw[red!\colorgrad!blue, line width=1.75pt, domain=-2.00 : 2.00, samples=101] plot[smooth] ({\x+\rt}, {\x*\x});
    
    \end{tikzpicture} 
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also of course add more steps, but then you would have to think about what to write as label for the *y* axis. (The code above is somewhat "hardened" and now also accepts floating numbers, so you can play around with different settings.)

Comment: Should I just add 20 frames to slow it down since it is too fast.

Comment: @Guest You can also decrease the frame rate: `\begin{animateinline}[controls, palindrome]{1}` would mean 1 frame per second.